# Is there a quicker way to change languages for speech-to-text?

Tags: keyboard, voice-recognition

I really love using speech-to-text in my SwiftKey keyboard, but I can't use different languages unless I go to Settings > Speech-to-text > Language. This is quite bothering and I hope there's a way to change language every time STT says "Speak now".

I don't want multilingual support like "Ciao, how are you?", I only want to choose STT language without going to Settings

Here's an example of what I want:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Just one tap on the world icon  to switch between languages:

[image]

Screenshot from Google Pixel 6 on Android 12  with Google keyboard.